# hidden form jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, html, forms, autofill

What I am trying to do is have a hidden form, that works with another script I am running which I all the tagging script. What it does is when you click users name it paste it into the textarea, that works fine. Now I want to get to complicated stuff, I want to also paste to a hidden textfield (which will be for a PM function)

Basically the html for the form:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<form class="frm-form" enctype="multipart/form-date" name="post" 
method="post" action="/primsgs">
<input id="username" type="text" name="username[]">
 <input type="text" title="" maxlength="64" 
value="You were tagged in a topic!" name="subject" readonly>
<textarea id="hidden_textarea_pm" wrap="virtual" name="message" >
<input type="submit" accesskey="s" tabindex="6" value="Send" name="post">
</form>
</div>
```

In the text area value I can place {USERNAME} for them to read it as them. Though the textfield area I need to have my click func work with this and the visible text area. 
Message in the hidden textarea I want to say {USERNAME} you have been tagged recently in a post. Check it out www.url.com/postlocation .

Which with the www.url.com/postlocation I'm trying to get it with jQuery. Then when the user who tagged the one user it will send the tagged user a PM.

Tag code:

```
(function($){
$(function(){ $('.username a').click(function(){return false});
$('.username a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();
var innerTxt=$(this).text();innerTxt=$.trim(innerTxt);
var $obj=$('.quick_reply_textarea');$obj.val($obj.val()+'@'+innerTxt+':');})}); })(jQuery);
```

If you understand what I'm saying please help me. I want a code that will work for what Im trying to do. Also if there is no tag click I don't want that PM hidden form to send or nothing. Any way possible? I do not have access to PHP either.

Please don't negative vote this, if you have a question please ask and I will answer. I don't know if I'm missing anything. I'm not an expert coder so

Comment: I don't totally understand you. But, if you want to send the user name to the php script. Why don't you use AJAX instead of submitting a hidden form?

Comment: can't involve PHP I don't have access directly to it. So What I wanted to do is when clicked username. Itll append it to the textarea ID and the textfield hidden class. And send it only if the hidden form is filled. The textarea should send no matter what. I believe you can see what I mean here http://easybbtutorials.forumotion.com/f7-css-questions

Comment: I don't get the point yet. Why would you use a hidden text area to hold your data? can't you save your data in a variable?

Comment: I'm not to sure what exactly you mean? I'm going to start a new post on this since I have close to everything i need just its not sending and its ruined the first code making it not work anymore